# How to get jqGrid current search criteria?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I need to get the exact same thing the jqGrid passes on the GET/POST _search parameter.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just to close this question I did this this the following line:

```
grid.getGridParam("postData").filters;
```

With this I get the filter expression the jqGrid generates when we're applying filters on its data.

Comment: This doesn't work for me when using `datatype: "json"`.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#myGrid').getGridParam("postData").filters;
```

will give you a string (i don't know why string. why not JSON)

```
"{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Name","op":"bw","data":"a"}]}"
```

rules have the search criteria. If i have multiple search criteria, all would be there

```
"{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Name","op":"bw","data":"a"},{"field":"Description","op":"bw","data":"d"}]}"
```

Comment: The new API mode will look like this:
$('#myGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', "postData").filters

Comment: I also don't understand why it returns a string and not JSON.

Answer (score 2):

```
var search = grid.getGridParam("postData").search;
```

...works for me.

Comment: Thanks!
My question body isn't quite correct, what I want isn't the _search which is a boolean but the filters that actually contains the json representation of the current filter applyed on the grid.
So the way of getting is: grid.getGridParam("postData").filters;

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you're asking for.