# jqGrid display search criteria from search dialog to main form

Tags: javascript, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a jqgrid that uses multiple search. I want to display the search criteria on the form hosting the jqgrid as a title heading. Is it possible to pass data between the search dialog and the form hosting the grid?

[How to get jqGrid current search criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217499/how-to-get-jqgrid-current-search-criteria) is not clear whether the criteria is being displayed on the search dialog or the hosting form.